# Missing events on previously empty partition when restarting kafka streams app

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a strange issue that I cannot understand how I can resolve. I have a kafka streams app (2.1.0) that reads from a topic with around 40 partitions. The partitions are using a range partition policy so at the moment some of them can be completely empty.

My issue is that during the downtime of the app one of those empty partitions was activated and a number of events were written to it. When the app was restored though, it read all the events from other partitions but it ignored the events already stored to the previous empty partition (the app has OffsetResetPolicy LATEST for the specific topic). On top of that when newer messages arrived to the specific partition it did consume them and somehow bypassed the previous ones.

My assumption is that `__consumer_offsets` does not have any entry for the specified partition when restoring but how can I avoid this situation without losing events. I mean the topic already exists
with the specified number of partitions.

Does this sound familiar to anybody ? Am I missing something, do I need to set some parameter to kafka because I cannot figure out why this is happening ?

Comment: shouldn't you be using `earliest` for the `auto.offset.reset`? "What to do **when there is no initial offset** in Kafka or if the current offset does not exist any more..."

Comment: Some partitions already have records, so If I use `earliest` on topic that essentially will lead to reprocessing data on these partitions.

Comment: Once again, `auto.offset.reset` ONLY takes effect "when there is no initial offset in Kafka or if the current offset does not exist any more [i.e. expired]". If your client have already read some partitions and have offsets committed, it will continue reading from those previously committed offsets after the restart.

Comment: Ok you are correct, my bad, if you have the same application id it will work as you mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behaviour.

Your empty partition does not have committed offset in `__consumer_offsets`. If there are no committed offsets for a partition, the offset policy specified in `auto.offset.rest` is used to decide at which offset to start consuming the events.

If `auto.offset.reset` is set to `LATEST`, your Streams app will only start consuming at the latest offset in the partition, i.e., after the events that were added during downtime and it will only consume events that were written to the partition after downtime.

If `auto.offset.reset` is set to `EARLIEST`, your Streams app will start from the earliest offset in the partition and read also the events written to the partition during downtime.

As @mazaneica mentioned in a comment to your question, `auto.offset.reset` only affects partitions without a committed offset. So your non-empty partitions will be fine, i.e., the Streams app will consume events from where it stopped before the downtime.